# Nicest way to turn "2015-03-18 22:00" into a Time object

Tags: ruby

I have three strings, pulled from a database:

- `"2015-03-18"` (the date the event occurs)
- `"22:00"` (the hour an event occurs)
- `"-05:00"` (the UTC offset in the location the event occurs).

I want to combine these three strings to produce a Ruby Time object. I'm doing:

```
utc_offset = "-05:00"
airtime = "22:00"
airday = "2015-03-18"

year,month,day,hour,minutes = airday.split("-").map(&:to_i) + airtime.split(":").map(&:to_i)
Time.new(year,month,day,hour,minutes,0,utc_offset)
```

This works; I'm just wondering if it's the correct/standard/idiomatic/clearest way.

Comment: are we talking pure ruby, or with rails ?

Comment: @MohhammedAbuShady Pure Ruby right now, but I'm very interested to hear the Rails situation too.

Comment: rails has `DateTime.parse`, you'd be able to do `DateTime.parse "#{airday} #{airtime} #{utc_offset}"` and thats it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using *[Time.parse](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html)*

> When ‘time’ is required, Time is extended with additional methods for
>   parsing and converting Times.

```
require 'time'

utc_offset = "-05:00"
airtime = "22:00"
airday = "2015-03-18"

time = Time.parse("#{airday} #{airtime} #{utc_offset}")
```

Comment: well this is interesting, didn't know that some classes might not have all their functions initially, are there any other classes like that too (that you know of) ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the way to do it.

```
Time.new(*airday.split("-"), *airtime.split(":"), 0, utc_offset)
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but merging airday and airtime first and then gsub, this is cleaner and simpler than what i was thinking

Answer (score 1):

How about this? http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime

```
require 'time'

raw_time    = '2015-03-18 22:00'
parsed_time = Time.strptime(raw_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') # 2015-03-18 22:00:00 +0100
```